# problem facing in integration of ROS and OPENCV

Tags: ros, cvbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello! i have picked code from cvbridge tutorial of ROS, followed all the steps then build package. node has been created but when i m trying to run that node after running image stream according to tutorial, nothing appear on screen. here is the code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
    
static const char WINDOW[] = "Image window";
 
   
class ImageConverter
{
     ros::NodeHandle nh_;
     image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
     image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
     image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
     
   public:
     ImageConverter()
       : it_(nh_)
     {
       image_pub_ = it_.advertise("out" , 1);
       image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/topic_imgtransport", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);
   
      cv::namedWindow(WINDOW);
     }
  
     ~ImageConverter()
     {
       cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW);
     }
  
     void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
     {
       cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
       try
       {
         cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
       }
       catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
       {
         ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
         return;
       }
   
    
       cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(50, 50), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
       cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
       cv::waitKey(3);
       
       image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
     }
};
   
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
     ImageConverter ic;
     ros::spin();
 
     return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63570/problem-facing-in-integration-of-ros-and-opencv/) by [jasmine](https://answers.ros.org/users/4986/jasmine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In some cases you need to add cv::startWindowThread() after cv:namedWindow(). In particular this is the case, if you do not call cv::waitKey() without arguments, i. e. not blocking until key pressed, after cv::imshow().

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2